# Shutdown Kafka Cluster and then Start Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, restart

I have a 2 Broker node kafka with 3 node ZooKeeper cluster. When Stopping and starting Kafka cluster, what are the steps I should take,
Do I go, stop 2 brokers individually first and then stop 3 zks individually?
And then start zks individually and 2 kafka brokers individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumptions**

- This is a production cluster and you don't want any data loss.
- You have partition replicas spanned across the brokers
- For each partition you have at least one replica on each broker
- all zks are accessible by each broker

This is how I would do it

1. Take down individual broker.
2. When one of the broker is down, then `describe` the topics to check if only replicas that are not shown, belong to broker which was taken down.
3. Restart the broker and again verify that all partitions are in sync before going for next broker.
4. Then stop-start each zk individually, each time tracking if all replicas and partitions are in sync. That way at least one zk is available for 2 brokers to maintain their meta data